# Why is a C++ Lambda function much faster as compare function than an equivalent object

Tags: c++, sorting, optimization, lambda

I am curious, why an implementation with a lambda function in my case is so much faster than an implementation with an equivalent object.
To give you an idea of the scale: with 10^4 values, the fast one takes much less than a second and the slow one takes tens of seconds. With 10^5 vales, the fast one still completes in under a second, but the slow one takes minutes.

I want to sort the values of two arrays in the same way as if I would sort one of them. It's easier to understand with an example:
[5 1 2 0]    becomes   [0 1 2 5]
[3 5 6 7]       to     [7 5 6 3]

There are various ways around the internet how to do that, but that's not what I want to ask.
I did two implementations: one using an object with overloaded operator() and one with a lambda function as "Compare".

The code below has the lambda function version uncommented. To use the compare object, just comment out what is in "compare using lambda function" and uncomment "compare using compare object".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void sortTwoVectorsByFirstVector(std::vector< float >& sortBySelf, std::vector< float >& sortByOther)
{
    // init sort indices
    std::vector < uint32_t > sortIndices(sortBySelf.size());
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sortIndices.size(); ++i) {
        sortIndices[i] = i;
    }

    //******** begin: compare using compare object
//    struct CompareClass {
//        std::vector< float > m_values;
//        inline bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
//        {
//            return (m_values[i] < m_values[j]);
//        }
//    } compareObject { sortBySelf };
//    std::sort(sortIndices.begin(), sortIndices.end(), compareObject);
    //******* end: compare using compare object

    //********  begin: compare using lambda function
    std::sort(sortIndices.begin(), sortIndices.end(), [&sortBySelf](size_t i, size_t j) {return sortBySelf[i] < sortBySelf[j];});
    //********  end: compare using lambda function

    // collect the sorted elements using the indices
    std::vector< float > sortedBySelf_sorted;
    std::vector< float > sortByOther_sorted;
    sortedBySelf_sorted.resize(sortBySelf.size());
    sortByOther_sorted.resize(sortBySelf.size());

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sortBySelf.size(); ++i) {
        sortedBySelf_sorted[i] = sortBySelf[sortIndices[i]];
        sortByOther_sorted[i] = sortByOther[sortIndices[i]];
    }

    sortBySelf.swap(sortedBySelf_sorted);
    sortByOther.swap(sortByOther_sorted);
}

float RandomNumber()
{
    return std::rand();
}
int main()
{
    int vectorSize = 100000;
    std::vector< float > a(vectorSize);
    std::vector< float > b(vectorSize);

    std::srand(100);
    std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), RandomNumber);
    std::generate(b.begin(), b.end(), RandomNumber);

    std::cout << "started" << std::endl;

    sortTwoVectorsByFirstVector(a, b);

    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
}
```

It would be cool, if someone could make clear, where this huge performance gap comes from.

Comment: Your manually written class copies the vector, the lambda expression does not.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manually written class copies the `vector`:

```
std::vector< float > m_values;  //<< By value
```

The lambda expression merely references it:

```
[&sortBySelf](size_t i, size_t j) {return sortBySelf[i] < sortBySelf[j];}
```

If you took `sortBySelf` by copy (without the `&`) then they would likely have similar performance.

Comment: Thank you! I now did it the other way round, changed "std::vector< float > m_values;" to "std::vector< float >& m_values;".
But what I do not understand is: The copy is done only once, when initializing (right?). This cannot take seconds for 10^5 elements.

Comment: @user3022712: `std::sort` is permitted to copy the functor it is given *any number of times*. I could see naive implementations copying that functor `O(log(n))` times at least.